# Netsuite 24 hour clock in formula(text)

Tags: datetime, netsuite

I am looking for the proper syntax for the 24 clock in a formula(text) in a NetSuite saved search.

Here is a sample of what i am using that output the 12 hour clock...

```
TO_CHAR({datecreated},'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')
```

And example output for this would be 12/31/2014 01:25:11

I would like the output to be 12/31/2014 13:25:11

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else finds this and needs to correct syntax it is

```
TO_CHAR({datecreated},'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```